# Convert each integer to a simple ASCII graph

Tags: bash

I have a file with a bunch of integers like this:

```
6
2
3
4
3
```

The goal is to convert those integers in stats like in a videogame, for example, if the number is 6, the stats must be `******----`, if the number is 4 the result must be `****------`.

I tried the following piece of code but it doesn't work:

```sh
# Here I put all the int in a variable.
intNumber=`cat /home/intNumbers.txt`

# This for is a loop to print as much * as the number says.
for i in `seq 1 $intNumber`
do
  echo -n "*"
  # This for loop is for printing - until reacing 10.
  for j in `seq $intNumber 10`
  do
    echo -n "-"
  done
done
```

Comment: When you use cat, intNumber will contain all of the data from that specific file. You have to use head to read the first line, then the second one.

Comment: The two `for` loops should be sequential, not the one embedded in the other, right?

Comment: @DorinBaba No, that's not how you loop over the lines in a file. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor which is about a related topic, but certainly shows how to do it correctly.

Comment: tags of a question are not determined by what OP presents initially, and they can change as answers arrive. SO permits 5 tags per question for a reason that question can be found easily later. Do check this meta post: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252079/tagging-a-question-based-on-its-answers

Comment: IMHO, SO allows 5 tags on a question to mention all relevant technologies related to question and answers. It enhances search visibility of the question for future visitors. I see different languages(eg--> awk, shell scripting, sed, perl) answers are mostly given(which is Good also people get different varieties of answers, can help multiple people at a time), so there shouldn't be any harm in adding relevant tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk '{s = sprintf("%*s", $1, ""); gsub(/ /, "*", s); p = sprintf("%*s", 10-$1, ""); gsub(/ /, "-", p); print s p}' file

******----
**--------
***-------
****------
***-------
```

A more readable version:

```sh
awk '{
   s = sprintf("%*s", $1, "")
   gsub(/ /, "*", s)
   p = sprintf("%*s", 10-$1, "")
   gsub(/ /, "-", p)
   print s p
}' file
```

Answer (score 6):

With Perl:

```
perl -ne 'print("*" x $_, "-" x (10-$_), "\n")' file
```

> `$_` contains current row

Output:

```
******----
**--------
***-------
****------
***-------
```

Answer (score 4):

Another awk, *keepin' it simple, sir*:

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
    s="**********----------"
}
{
    print substr(s,11-$1,10)
}' file
```

Output:

```
******----
**--------
***-------
****------
***-------
```

Similar for bash:

```
#!/bin/bash
s="**********----------"
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "${s:((10-$line)):10}"
done < file
```

A more generic approach for awk could be, for example:

```
$ awk -v m=10 '{            # desired maximum number of chars
    t=""                    # temp var
    for(i=1;i<=m;i++)       # loop to max
        if(i<=$1)           # up to threshold value from file
            sub(/^/,"*",t)  # prepend a *
        else                # after threshold
            sub(/$/,"-",t)  # append a -
     print t
}' file
```

Some input checking could be in order.

Comment: IMO It is good but not scalable. What if total length is 1000 instead of 10

Comment: You should make another question for that. :D

Comment: It is not my question :) just an academic discussion. I always upvote your awk answers

Comment: Then you can just do `awk 'BEGIN{max=10; p=s=sprintf("%*s",max,""); gsub(/ /,"*",s); gsub(/ /,"-",p); s=s p;}'`

Answer (score 4):

Minimizing the work you have to do per input line for efficiency:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    lgth = 10
    curr = base = sprintf("%*s",lgth,"")
    gsub(/ /,"*",curr)
    gsub(/ /,"-",base)
}
{ print substr(curr,1,$1) substr(base,$1+1) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
******----
**--------
***-------
****------
***-------
```

or borrowing @JamesBrowns idea of indexing into a single string:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    lgth = 10
    curr = base = sprintf("%*s",lgth,"")
    gsub(/ /,"*",curr)
    gsub(/ /,"-",base)
    line = curr base
}
{ print substr(line,(lgth-$1)+1,lgth) }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
******----
**--------
***-------
****------
***-------
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't read the entire input file into memory. Instead, process one line at a time.

The following also demonstrates how to do this more succinctly in Bash.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
ten='----------'
while IFS='' read -r num; do
    printf -v graph '%10.10s' "${ten:$num}"
    echo "${graph// /\*}"
done < intNumbers.txt
```

`printf -v graph` places the output in the variable `graph`, and we then use a Bash parameter substitution to replace the space padding from `printf` with asterisks.

Demo: https://ideone.com/wE6fpm

Doing this entirely in Bash is attractive if you end up doing this a lot; you generally want to avoid external processes especially in repeated code (though of course [don't repeat yourself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself); put this in a function then.)

If you genuinely want to convert a file of numbers into a bunch of graphs, a single Awk process is still much better; the shell isn't particularly good at that. I'm imagining you have a different application where you occasionally need to format a number as a graph in various places in a Bash script.

Comment: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) @EdMorton would have mentioned this few dozen times

Comment: Yeah, if you really have a bunch of numbers in a file, an Awk solution would be much better. I'm imagining the OP needs this for something different actually (though if you are writing an action game in Bash, you are probably in for some serious trouble anyway).

Comment: Yes I understand that but suggesting right tool for right job is our job, isn't it?

Comment: Fair enough; I'll add a note about that.

Comment: While I agree with @anubhava by mentioning Ed's comment, it must be mentioned that even though 99% of the questions can be solved easily with awk, we must assume that maybe the OP actually only asked a part of the question and a for loop is more interesting to him. Maybe there are still scripts to be run in the loop itself or other actions to be performed. Overall, if it is just text manipulation, yes use awk but otherwise, a secondary pure bash solution is never bad.

Answer (score 1):

A riff on tripleee's answer:

```sh
# Repeat a character a specified number of times
#
# parameters
# - character
# - count
#
# usage: strRepeat "*" 60
#
str_repeat() {
    local char=$1 count=$2
    local result
    # string of count spaces
    printf -v result "%*s" "$count" ""
    # replace spaces with the char
    echo "${result// /$char}"
}

while read -r num; do
    printf '%s%s\n' "$(str_repeat '*' "$num")" "$(str_repeat '-' $((10-num)))"
done < intNumbers.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another GAWK solution:

```
awk -v OFS="*" '{NF=($1+1); $1=""; print gensub(/ /,"-","g",sprintf("%-10s",$0))}' file

# -v OFS="*"
# [Sets the output field separator to an asterisk]

# NF=($1+1)
# [Defines the number of fields in the line as 1 more
# than the value in the first (and only) input field.
# If you printed the first line, it would now be "6******"]

# $1=""
# [Deletes the first field in the line, leaving only asterisks]

# sprintf("%-10s",$0)
# [Formats the line as 10 characters, left-justified.
# The missing characters on the right are blank spaces]

# gensub(/ /,"-","g",sprintf("%-10s",$0))
# [Replaces all blank spaces in the sprintf-formatted
# line with hyphens]

# print
# [Prints the line as modified by gensub]
```

Answer (score 0):

With Python:

```
python -c "import sys
> for s in sys.stdin: n=int(s); print('*'*n + '-'*(10-n))" < file
```